# Retract Suggested Edits

Tags: support, suggested-edits, reviewing

Is there a way to retract a previously rejected/accepted Suggested Edit?
Something like Close Votes and Reopen Votes, for example.

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to undo the edit, or change your accept/reject vote?

Comment: @AshleyNunn I know I can rollback an accepted edit, I mean the second one but I don't think it's possible, isn't it?

Comment: I am looking into that for you - I just wanted to make sure I get the right information for you before I answer :)

Comment: Pretty sure you can't change your choice in a review, no.

Comment: You can't change it.

Source : [Meta stack exchange question about the same thing](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171095/any-way-to-change-my-review-of-suggested-edit)

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau ok, I thought so. Thank you, anyway.